# Can't distribute a Mac command line tool

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, command-line-interface

I've created a simple command line tool with Xcode that we need to use internally in our company and distribute to clients.

I've archived this tool using almost every type of certificate possible "Mac Developer", "Developer ID Application", "Mac App Distribution", etc. but when this tool is opened in any other machine, the user is faced with the typical *"App can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer"*.

I know this alert can be ignored going to "System Preferences" -> "Security & Privacy" and allow those type of apps, but that's not what I'm looking for. I need to be able to just open this tool without changing any settings.

The alert:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the command line to package the tool, that is by creating a tar and/or zip file using the tar or zip commands?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How would that help?

Comment: Just to double check: are you sure you have a valid and up to date Developer ID?

Comment: @AlejandroCotilla, I meant that as far as I know the same check is not performed if you unpack something from the command line or even double-click a zip file in the Finder. Of course this might mean the user has to do more during installation or and you might need to write some kind of install script for the user to execute.

Comment: @RishiG Yes, I do have a valid and up to date Developer ID, the same certificates work for a MacOS app.

Comment: How is the user launching the program? Are they double-clicking it in the Finder? Are they running it from a shell (command line) in Terminal? I would not expect that dialog for a program run from a command line.

Comment: @KenThomases Double-clicking it in the Finder shows the dialog, running it from Terminal prints out "Permission denied".

Comment: "Permission denied" is presumably because the execute bits of the file's mode didn't survive the transfer between computers. Try `chmod a+x /path/to/DeeplinkCreator` and then try running it again. Or change how you're transferring the file to a method which preserves the mode bits.

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks, doing `chmod a+x` lets me run it from terminal without any issues. Storing it in a dmg or zip also keeps the executable intact, so no need for `chmod a+x`. Still would be nice to execute it with a double-click.

Comment: Are you able to execute it with a double-click on your development machine? Command line tools don't usually work that way. Well, double-clicking them just launches Terminal and automatically issues the path to the executable as a command in a shell. Also, how are you transferring it? Given that the file mode was getting lost, perhaps code signature info was, too. Perhaps zipping or tarring it will preserve those.

Answer (score 0):

How are you exactly building the version?

1. On the Menu Bar select `Product > Archive`.
2. After the build, the Organizer window opens.
3. Select your version and klick `Export...` on the right side of the window.
4. On the next window select `Developer ID / Distribute directly to customers`.
5. On the next screen select `Automatically manage signing`.
6. After that you will see a screen with a summary of your team, your certificate, etc.
7. Klick on "Export" and you're done.

Comment: The windows and options you're describing are for a MacOS app, this is not a MacOS app, is a Command Line Tool.